# why are standards for teminology and diagramming notation as defined by UML so important for the success of the object oriented approach?

Tags: uml

I try to research every pages about UML.
There none of impact about UML..
anyone have this experienced before?
what i mean is the standard of terminology and diagramming itself.. and the reason why uml so important for the success of the object oriented...

Comment: It's because the impact has been patchy at best. I've never met anyone in the software industry who feels it is necessary (though many who have been required to use it, but all felt it was a waste of time). Why do you assume it has been so important for the success of the OO approach? Could it be that you've pasted in a homework question?!

Comment: "Standards for terminology" - this might refer to "design patterns".

Comment: Frankly, I don't think that UML is really all that important - in my whole work experience, the only time when I've actually had to draw any was on interviews. Others have shared similar experiences. I think that if it were to suddenly disappear tomorrow, not many would notice, and it wouldn't really affect OO design much.

Comment: When your teacher gives you an F for saying UML is useless, be sure to point the teacher to this discussion. :)

Answer (score 3):

Before UML, each methodologist with a book to sell would invent their own notation. Some had triangles one way up for inheritance, some the other.

After UML, each methodologist with a book to sell invents a new type of UML diagram and gets it added to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Object orientation was in fact pretty succesful long before UML came along. However, it is convenient that a lot of programmers have been exposed to a common language - it makes it easier to communicate ideas. Before UML, one used to have pre-design meetings to explain the notatition to one's teams (I had to do this when using Jacobson's Objectory method prior to UML), nowadays you can assume (possibly wrongly, I admit) that they will have some familiarity with what you are talking about.

Comment: In practice I find that people's knowledge of UML is flaky, and generally limited to basics (and even then people often get it wrong). There's also that curious notion that _any_ object diagram is "UML" - I've met quite a few people who seem to be convinced that is the case - and, for example, thing that VS class designer produces UML output. All in all, I'd say that the impact is pretty low even for what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The book ["Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135974445) goes through many of the components of the UML diagrams and describe their use in designing an OO architecture. For some of the diagrams, the author's suggestions boiled down to "keep it simple". Use case diagrams, for example, is shafted in favor for just written use cases. An alternative for complex state diagrams is offered in the form of a state transition table.

At the beginning of the book, the author describes several principles for OO design, such as the dependency inversion principle and the single responsibility. Those have nothing to do with UML. UML is a communication tool which purpose is to allow one to visualise the architecture. Different components of UML has a different purpose- class diagrams for the architecture, object diagrams how objects interact with each other, sequence diagrams for interaction with objects (and itself) over time.

So is UML responsible for the success of OO design? I think UML coming along shows that OO design is worthwhile because UML is to used to present OO design. Same way with that Jackson diagram was used for structural programming.

Answer (score 0):

what i mean is the standard of terminology and diagramming itself.. and the reason why uml so important for the success of the object oriented...